# Android OpenGL ES RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY implementation

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to understand `RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY` so that I could save battery life wherever possible.. I made this sample application so that GlSurfaceView is updated with random color only when the random number `temp` is greater than 50... If the value of `temp` is less than 50, I want it to retain the last random color.. But in this code sample, it is not retaining it but making the screen go black forever!

Basically I want to know if my implementation of `RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY` correct...

```
package com.blob.blob;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class OpenGLActivity extends Activity implements Renderer
{
    GLSurfaceView glView;
    Random rand ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle s)
    {
        super.onCreate(s);
        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setRenderer(this);
        glView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        rand = new Random();
        setContentView(glView);

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    {           
        int temp = rand.nextInt(100);

        if(temp > 50)
        {
        glView.requestRender();

        gl.glClearColor(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), 1);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }       

    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

        Log.d("OpenglTest", "Surface Changed");
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        Log.d("OpenglTest", "Surface Created");
    }

    public void onPause()
    {

        super.onPause();
        glView.onPause();


    }


    public void onResume()
    {       
        super.onResume();
        glView.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by going black forever? can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @JoséIgnacio 
Sorry for super late reply.. Black means the screen is quite literally black and the `onDrawFrame()` method is not called again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY` means "do not call `onDrawFrame()` unless something explicitly requests rendering with `requestRender()`".  Your code snippet is calling `requestRender()` from within `onDrawFrame()`, so nothing will ever happen.

The idea behind `requestRender()` is that nothing is drawn until some other thread has decided that rendering needs to happen.  The [SurfaceView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) note that it "may be called from any thread", which is necessary for this method to have any value, because the renderer thread is just sitting there waiting for somebody to wake it up.

Comment: Haha.. makes sense..

Comment: In addition, I've noticed that there are occasionally also "uninvited" onDrawFrame() calls that it's good to prepare for. I now think that doing a requestRender() ignites at least one render pass.